# onclick has to be clicked twice to fire

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

My onclick function won't fire unless it is clicked twice.  I am very new to javascript but so far i trie moving around the var obj line, and changing the =="none" to "none"?"empty"; which are both things I didn't understand but saw other people did to fix this problem.  Neither worked.

```
<a href="#" onClick="showDiv('show1')">+</a>

function showDiv(id){
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
if( obj.style.display == "none") {
obj.style.display='block'
}
else{
obj.style.display='none'    
}
}


<div id="show1">
Roughly 2-3 months.
</div>
```

Comment: Show the markup for the div with "show1" id.

Comment: Use classes to show/hide elements.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is, that you use the `style` property of the element directly. Assuming, that you did not set `obj.style.display = "none";` in your code explicitly, the value remains `undefined` until the first click. After the first click it is set and everything works like you want it to.

To solve it use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.getComputedStyle) to access the element's style. This includes all styles set via CSS:

```
function showDiv(id){
  var obj = document.getElementById(id),
      compStyle = window.getComputedStyle( obj );
  if( compStyle.display == "none") {
    obj.style.display='block'
  } else {
    obj.style.display='none'    
  }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me.  when I copied it directly into my code, the function stopped working completely. when i added the compstyle=window into it, it still required two clicks.

Comment: just take me out back and shoot me.  Your right.  my comp must not have uploaded the code when i tried it.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use [strict equal operators](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/07/truth-equality-and-javascript/) to prevent from undefined style rule.

I would rather use addEventListener instead of onclick to keep my code cleaner, here is a jsfiddle with my version (some extras as dataset and triple conditional are there, but they are not necessarily needed in your example)

```
var showDiv = function (ev) {

  var id = ev.currentTarget.dataset.id;
  var obj = document.getElementById('show' + id);

  obj.style.display = (obj.style.display === "none") ? 'block' : 'none';
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mindcookin/06nvkay7/4/